# What's the best way to vectorise text data in NLTK if i want to preserve the order of sentence?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp, nltk

I'm classifying text data and want to feed it into a model but I am stuck with an issue. I don't want to use CountVectorizer because it doesn't preserve it's structure but also don't want to manually convert each word into an array to due inefficiency.

What methods can I use that will help in such a context.

Thanks

Comment: if you are using NN I suggest you: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer

Comment: Yes I’ve already tokenised the words, just need to convert it numerically but want to do so using a method that preserves the sentences structure

Comment: There's not a simple answer to this, the right way to encode a sentence and maintain structure is still a topic of active research. Look at Transformers/BERT, Universal Sentence Encoders, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to the question but provides a perspective.
If sequence of words is more important than a bag-of-words approach, then using graph based models would help. For example, [pycrfsuite](https://github.com/scrapinghub/python-crfsuite/blob/master/examples/CoNLL%202002.ipynb) is a good starting point.